# Adding new Class file destroys program

Tags: php, object, include

so I've ran across a strange error while attempting to build my class files for my program. I have never ran into this problem with PHP before especially Object Oriented PHP. Basically the fastest way of explaining it is adding a new file makes another one not exist. I will demonstrate below:

FILE #1

```
//process.php
require_once '../../inc/config.php';
include 'ProcessApplication/ProcessApplication.php';
$processor = new ProcessApplication($CONN);

if($processor->getConn()){
    list($general, $phone) = $processor->processGeneralInfo($_REQUEST['general_information'];
}
```

I'm not going to include all code from the ProcessApplication.php file because it is not relevant.

FILE #2

```
class ProcessApplication{
    protected $conn = null;
    function __construct($CONN){
        $this->conn = $CONN;
    }
    public function getConn(){
        return $this->conn;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}//end ProcessApplication class
```

FILE #3, simple test program to make sure inheritence is working correctly

```
class ProcessApplicationQuery extends ProcessApplication{
    public function getReady(){
        if($this->getConn()){ //edited as of most recent update
            print "Ready";
        }else{
            print "not Ready";
        }
    } 
}
```

So far file #3 was not included, and the program still worked. At this point I have now included it into FILE #1 and I don't know why

```
//process.php
require_once '../../inc/config.php';
include 'ProcessApplication/ProcessApplication.php';
include 'ProcessApllication/ProcessApplicationQuery.php'; //2nd class file added

$processor = new ProcessApplication($CONN);

if($processor->getConn()){
    list($general, $phone) = $processor->processGeneralInfo($_REQUEST['general_information'];
    $processor->getReady(); //added to check file #3 was working
}
```

So now that FILE #1 has been updated. I get `Fatal Error: failed to open file stream '../../inc/config.php'` even though it was working just fine, and then I undo all the updates, and bring FILE #1 back to its original state, and the program is still failing.

Based off of everything I've learned about object oriented programming both in PHP and JAVA this small set of programs should be working correctly. Unless its something simple I have forgotten I can't see where my error is. I'm getting really frustrated, I hope this makes sense to someone.

===UPDATES===

FILE #1 now looks like this and this has been updated to match the correct solution to the problem

```
 //process.php
include '../../inc/config.php';
include 'ProcessApplication/ProcessApplication.php';
include 'ProcessApplication/ProcessApplication.php';

$processor = new ProcessApplicationQuery($CONN);
if($processor->getConn()){
    list($general, $phone) = $processor->processGeneralInfo($_REQUEST['general_information'];

    $processor->getReady(); // this prints out "ready"
}
```

Comment: The scope resolution operator (:: ) is for "static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class". getConn is none of those. Just use getConn() instead of parent::getConn().

Comment: okay I will try that, before I do that though, does it order of inheritence make sense to you? Since `File #2` is where everything is going, should that be the parent class and then everything else children? I'm just trying to make sure my programming standards are correct.

Comment: The inheritance looks OK, but it's just really snippets, so I don't know the architecture of what you're going to end up with.

Comment: okay I have made some edits, I tried just using `getConn()` but that didn't work, so I added the `$this->getConn()` and that worked but right now I'm only getting "not Ready", shouldn't it be giving me 'ready' if I'm passing through an active connection object?

Comment: new ProcessApplication($CONN); and new ProcessApplicationQuery(); are different objects. You don't need the first. Just use $query = new ProcessApplicationQuery($CONN); as that incorporates everything from the parent class.

Comment: oh that makes sense, because I would pass it the connection object, and by default it would be picked up by the constuctor function. Excellent well I tested it and everything is working perfectly. If you want to submit an answer I'll definitely accept :)

Comment: OK, I put that in an answer. Glad everything worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ProcessApplicationQuery inherits everything from ProcessApplication, you do not need both:

```
$processor = new ProcessApplication($CONN);
$query = new ProcessApplicationQuery();
```

This creates two different objects, and $processor is the only one that has $CONN.

Instead, pass $CONN directly to the final class, like:

```
$query = new ProcessApplicationQuery($CONN);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much for all of your help I really learned a lot today!